# OpenOffice Secure?

Tags: windows, openoffice

As I know OpenOffice was mantained by Oracle earlier. I want to use it now but I am concerned if it is possible that some developer/programmer can smuggle malware into the programm code? OO was extensively used in linux  before and a vast comunity  was checking the code. How is this problem solved now? Is it realy safe to use? I mean safe in terms of no malware spyware etc. is in the program code. I am using Windows.

Comment: You could always use MicroSoft Office - after all, everything MicroSoft makes is **Totally Secure** right? ;-) Actually, @David is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Use Libreoffice.  That is the community developed and maintained successor to the Openoffice.   Oracle donated Openoffice to Apache, and IBM also donated a fair bit of their code base of Symphony to the Apache Openoffice project, but most community development is taking place around Libreoffice.